# Как очистить объекты на форме через javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть несколько полей ввода текста, несколько чекбоксов и один выпадающий список внутри формы. Их нужно очистить и выставить значения по умолчанию через скрипт, который вызывается нажатием одной кнопки. Метод reset для формы не предлагать.

Comment: И почему же его не предлагать?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если не метод reset, то:

```
<input type="reset">
```

То же самое, но без javascript.

Comment: Извиняюсь. Как раз <input type="reset"> мне не надо.

Comment: Тогда `<input type="button" onclick="this.form.reset()">`. Если значения по умолчанию задаются скриптом, то тоже могу написать способ.

Answer (score -3):

```
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i in forms) {
    forms[i].value = "";
}
```

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ описанием решения, чтобы пользователям было легче понять ваш код.